# i2c requires restart before bus access

Tags: python, raspbian-jessie, i2c

I have a Pi3 running Jesse and I am running some standard Python scripts to access the i2c bus to read voltage from an ADS1115.

After a reboot I have found I need to run the following to allow the bus to be available even although I have I2C enabled:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    sudo rmmod i2c_bcm2708
    sudo rmmod i2c_dev
    sudo modprobe i2c_bcm2708
    sudo modprobe i2c_dev
```

Running i2cdetect -y 1 before the above times out at each address scanned, afterwards the response is instant and my script runs and continues to perform flawlessly.

I would like assistance in tracking down the cause of the problem as the i2c bus should be available without running the reset lines above.

Thank you

Additional info:

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
i2c_dev                 5859  0 
i2c_bcm2708             4834  0
```

etc

Comment: Do you get the i2cdetect problem if you boot with the ADS1115 disconnected from  the bus?

Comment: That's a good question Joan.  Sadly it persists with everything off the bus.

Comment: Oh dear, that's a pity.  Slow i2cdetect (something like a second an address) has been reported a few times.  I don't remember how they were resolved.  In your case I would update to the latest firmware (sudo rpi-update) to confirm it isn't an old firmware issue.